add a button for transcription to a Django form
I am building a website and have views with Django forms. I want to add a transcription button to each field in the Django form
class PostForm(StylishForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ["title", "body", "upload"]
        widgets = {
            "owner": forms.HiddenInput(),
        }

and give the user the option either to fill the form by typing or pressing the button to transcribe then filling the field.
# add new 
def add(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.owner = request.user
            post.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("view_posts"))
    else:
        form = PostForm()
    return render(
        request,
        "posts/index.html",
        {
            "form": form,
        },
    )

I have prepared the function to use whisper api for transcription.
def record_audio(request):
    RATE = 16000
    CHUNK = 1024
    recordings = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'recordings') 
    # Ensure the folder exists
    if not os.path.exists(recordings):
        os.makedirs('recordings')
    
    # Define the path to save the audio file
    file_path = os.path.join(recordings, 'output.wav')

    # def callback(data_input, frame_count, time_info, status):
    #     wav_file.writeframes(data_input)
    #     return None, pyaudio.paContinue
    
    with wave.open(file_path, "wb") as wav_file:
        wav_file.setnchannels(1)  # Mono channel
        wav_file.setsampwidth(2)  # 16-bit samples
        wav_file.setframerate(16000)  # 16kHz sample rate

        audio = pyaudio.PyAudio()
        stream = audio.open(
            format=pyaudio.paInt16,
            channels=1,
            rate=RATE,
            input=True,
            frames_per_buffer=CHUNK,
        )

        for _ in range(0, RATE // CHUNK):
            wav_file.writeframes(stream.read(CHUNK))
        stream.stop_stream()
        stream.close()
        audio.terminate()

    audio_file= open(file_path, "rb")
    transcription = client.audio.transcriptions.create(
    model="whisper-1", 
    file=audio_file
    )
    print(transcription.text)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("view_posts"))

But, I cannot get my head around to send the text to the form field.
My html template looks like this:
 <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="post-tab-pane" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="post-tab"
        tabindex="0">
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{% url 'add' %}" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {% for field in post_form %}
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="form-labels">{{ field.label }}</div>
                {{ form.media }}

                <div class="form-fields">{{ field }}</div>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Save</button>
        </form>
    </div>

My issue I cannot think of a way to use text from transcription and populate the fields of the form selectively to toggle between both methods. I tried to find any examples on the internet but could not find any resource.
